# Пытаться, стараться и пробовать

Tags: выбор-слова

Лингво переводит слова *пытаться* и *пробовать* как *try, attempt*. С другой стороны, словарь Ефремова говорит, что *пытаться* значит то же, что и *стараться*.

Есть ли какая-то разница между этими словами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(в рамках близких значений)

**пытаться** - совершать целенаправленные действия в надежде на получение результата

**пробовать** - пытаться, будучи неуверенным в пригодности выбранного способа

**стараться** - в рамках выбранного метода действий прикладывать усилия к получению наилучшего результата

Answer (score 3):

Если коротко, то это синонимы, так же как и try и attempt. И так же как и try и attempt **оба** эти слова могут значить и "делать попытку", и "стараться".

Если подлиннее, то "пробовать" - это позднее заимствование из латыни (probare) через польский (próba, próbować) или же немецкий (Probe).

А "пытать(ся)" - славянское слово означающее "спрашивать". Однако же в современном русском языке "пытать" обыкновенно означает "допрос с пристрастием" (torture), а "пытаться" - как раз синоним "пробовать". "Пытать" в значении "спрашивать" встречается довольно редко.

Answer (score 2):

Они во многих случаях взаимозаменимы, но у каждого свой оттенок.

Интуитивно представляется так:

**стараться** — ясный метод достижения цели, более или менее вероятный успех;

**пытаться** — ясный метод, но успех далеко не гарантирован;

**пробовать** — успех не гарантирован, и даже метод может быть неверным.

Answer (score 0):

Словарь Ожегова
ПРО́БОВАТЬ, -бую, -буешь; -анный; несовер.
1. кого (что). Испытывать, проверять. Пробовать свои силы. Пробовать артиста на какую-нибудь роль.
2. что. Есть для пробы, чтобы определить вкус, готовность чего-нибудь. Пробовать кушанье.
3. с неопред. Пытаться, стараться что-н. сделать. Пробовал объясниться.
Толковый словарь Ушакова
ПЫТАТЬСЯ, пытаюсь, пытаешься, несовер. 1. (совер. попытаться). Делать попытку, стараться, пробовать что нибудь сделать. «Он напрасно пытается закурить: отсырелый табак не принимает огня.»